# how to send sms to contact saved in database through an android app?

Tags: android

i m developing an app which take message as input and sends it to the predefined numbers     stored in data base ! know the problem is i am inserting numbers in database when the app is loaded in **oncreate()** method  every time i send message at first if it send message to 4 number the on secnd attempt it'll send sms to 8 numbers and tired to move my data insertion code so that it will only insert data once not at every load but its not working please can any one helppp thankss !!

```
 btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {  
            //loop++;

                 db.open();
                 //loop++;
                  long id;


                  id = db.insertTitle(
                            "5556");  
                    id = db.insertTitle(
                            "5556");  

                    id = db.insertTitle(
                            "5556");  

                    id = db.insertTitle(
                            "5556");  

                 db.close();


             message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
            if ( message.length()>0 && message.length()<200)                
            {
                 db.open(); 
                 Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
                 if (c.moveToFirst())
                 { 


                     String phoneNo; 

                     do { phoneNo=c.getString(1) ;  
                        sendSMS(phoneNo,message);    
                      count++;
                        // db.DisplayTitle(c);
                        Toast.makeText(DatabaseSmsActivity.this,"sms no : "+count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                     } while (c.moveToNext());
                 }
                 db.close();
                // Toast.makeText(DatabaseSmsActivity.this,"Total SMS sent : "+count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }       


            else
                {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Please enter message.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

        }
    });
```

}

Comment: can you please share the code you are using with us?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply here is code which on botton click insert number to database and fetch them to send sms plzz help !!

Answer (score 0):

Dont Insert the Number everytime onCreate() calls just Insert it once and from the time update that number with the previous one. I think this will solve your problem

Comment: preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);            //Type mismatch: cannot convert from SharedPreferences to Preferences SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor  = preferences.edit();   //The method edit() is undefined for the type Preferences                                                      these error are cumin if i fix them app is force closing ? whats wrong ?

Comment: Murat Nafiz thanks for your help !! errors are removed its running but nothings happens on button click i think data is not inserting !!

Answer (score 0):

With this code everytime user clicks the button, the number `5556` is inserted to database four times. Wich means when user clicks the button again, another four `5556` rows added.

I think you are trying to make, when the user click button just send sms to predefined numbers in database which are 4 number?

If so:

Add a static variable to your activity

```
public static final String PREFS = "prefs";
private SharedPreferences preferences;
```

on your activity's onCreate method call a function like `enterNumbersToDatabase()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    enterNumbersToDatabase();
}
```

enterNumbersToDatabase function:

```
private void enterNumbersToDatabase(){
if(!preferences.getBoolean("isNumbersAddedToDB", false)){

db.open();
long id;

id = db.insertTitle("5556");  
id = db.insertTitle("5556");  
id = db.insertTitle("5556");  
id = db.insertTitle("5556");  
    db.close();
SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor  = preferences.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("isNumbersAddedToDB", true)
preferencesEditor.commit();
} 
}
```

And in your button's onClick function, skip the `adding numbers to database part` and you'll be fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor  = preferences.edit(); //The method edit() is undefined for the type Preferences

Comment: @ Murat Nafiz can you plzzz help !!